Jolt nested conditions
I would like to check a condition and based on the type, would like to check another condition.
For BookingType:3, If TrackingList is available in the input, the output should have a flag "TrackingAvailable": "Y". For all other booking types, we should not display this flag.
So far, I can check if TrackingList is available in the input and display the TrackingAvailable flag.
However, I am unable to figure out how to add another condition for BookingType
Sample input, jolt spec, and output are below. We need to update the jolt spec to add the BookingType condition as well such that TrackingAvailable is displayed only for BookingType:3
Input
{
  "Booking": [
    {
      "BookingLines": {
        "BookingLine": [
          {
            "Metadata": {
              "TrackingList": {
                "Tracking": [
                  {
                    "TrackingNumber": "1232131231"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "BookingType": "1"
    }
  ]
}

Jolt Spec
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Booking[&1].&",
          "BookingLines": {
            "BookingLine": {
              "*": {
                "Metadata": {
                  "TrackingList": {
                    "Tracking": "null"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "BookingLines": {
            "BookingLine": "Booking[&2].BookingLines.BookingLine"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Booking[&1].&",
          "BookingLines": {
            "BookingLine": {
              "*": {
                "Metadata": {
                  "TrackingList": {
                    "Tracking": {
                      "null": {
                        "#N": "Booking[&8].BookingLines.BookingLine[&5].Metadata.TrackingAvailable"
                      },
                      "*": {
                        "#Y": "Booking[&8].BookingLines.BookingLine[&5].Metadata.TrackingAvailable"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

output

{
  "Booking": [
    {
      "BookingLines": {
        "BookingLine": [
          {
            "Metadata": {
              "TrackingAvailable": "Y"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}


does this work for you?
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Booking[&1].&",
          "BookingLines": {
            "BookingLine": {
              "*": {
                "Metadata": {
                  "TrackingList": {
                    "Tracking": "null"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "BookingLines": {
            "BookingLine": "Booking[&2].BookingLines.BookingLine"
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
 ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Booking": {
        "*": {
          "*": "Booking[&1].&",
          "BookingType": {
            "@": "Booking[&2].&1",
            "3": {
              "@(2,BookingLines)": {
                "BookingLine": {
                  "*": {
                    "Metadata": {
                      "TrackingList": {
                        "Tracking": {
                          "null": {
                            "#N": "Booking[&10].BookingLines.BookingLine[&5].Metadata.TrackingAvailable"
                          },
                          "*": {
                            "#Y": "Booking[&10].BookingLines.BookingLine[&5].Metadata.TrackingAvailable"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

